# Call 'Move or Copy' Dialog

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

In EXCEL there is an on-board 'Move or Copy' dialog, which can be started by clicking right on one or more sheets. The advantage of this feature is that a little window (see picture) is opened, and the user can select the destination. I wanted to add this routine to an existing sub. I know how to copy a sheet using VBA, that's not a problem, I wanted the same little window, and I was wondering if I can use the on-board routine. I have tried recording, but the window for selecting the destination did not occur in the code. Of course, I can simply rebuilt it, but why reinventing the wheel?
Is there a way of calling the routine?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a built-in dialog:

```
application.Dialogs(xldialogworkbookmove).Show
```

You can also use `xldialogworkbookcopy` and you should basically get the same dialog but with the checkbox at the bottom checked.

Comment: With your help I could write the following sub:  `Sub move_sheets() ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Select Application.Dialogs(xlDialogWorkbookCopy).Show , ActiveWorkbook.Name End Sub`